# Async/Await not working for VueX getter but works for log

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I have an object of convos with *userIDs* that I need to loop through and, inside the loop, I need to make a call to Firebase to get the corresponding *userName* and then return an object with the convos, userNames, and userIDs.

I have tried using the async/await and the result I get from console.log is correct but my return statement directly after that, is undefined. Why is this happening? They are receiving the same object.

**store.js** getter snippet

```
getConvosObj: state => {
  var convoObj = {};
  var userConvos = state.userProfile.convos;
  async function asyncFunction() {
    for (const key in userConvos) {
      if (userConvos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const userID = userConvos[key];
        var userName;
        await fire.database().ref('/users/' + userID + '/userName').once('value', async (snapshot) => {
          userName = await snapshot.val();
          convoObj[key] = {userName, userID}
        })
      }
    }
    console.log(convoObj);   //result: correct object
    return convoObj;         //result: undefined
  }
  asyncFunction();
}
```

Comment: How do you know your function return `undefined`?

Comment: I assume you think that `getConvosObj` will return `convoObj`? Because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: By design, getters are not meant to be asynchronous. As instead, they should return a certain store state and will be reactively updated when state changes. The fact, that code example above is quite hard to predict only proves that concept. Such approach also has performance flaws. Please, try to stick with original idea: calling actions -> changing state with mutations -> returning state with getters. This way flow is clear and debuggable.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to user the `getConvosObj` to return `convoObj`. I'm fairly new to Vue so I didn't remember that I shouldn't do asynchronous stuff in getters. I've restructured it the way sosmii suggested below and it works now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why is this happening ?

Because you called async function synchronously.
lets make your code simpler.

```
getConvosObj: state => {
    async function asyncFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    asyncFunction();
}
```

at this point, your `getConvosObj()` will return **nothing**, because `getConvosObj()` ends before `asyncFunction()` ends.
you need to wait until your `asyncFunction()` ends, then your code should be like this:

```
getConvosObj: async state => { // <- changed here
  async function asyncFunction() {
    // ...
  }

  await asyncFunction(); // <- changed here too
}
```

but **you should not do like this**, because getters are not meant to be asynchronous by design.
this may work, but you should try a different approach.

## So what should you do ?

### Use actions before using getters

this is a basic approach.

async functions should be in actions.
so your store should be like this:

```
export default () => 
  new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      convoObj: null
    },
    mutations: {
      updateConvoObj(state, payload) {
        state.convoObj = payload;
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async fetchAndUpdateConvoObj({ state, commit }) {
        const fetchUserData = async userId => {
          const snapShot = await fire.database().ref('/users/' + userID + '/userName').once('value');
          const userName = snapShot.val();

          return {
            userName: userName,
            userID: userId
          }
        }

        const userConvos = state.userProfile.convos;

        let convoObj = {};
        for (const key in userConvos) {
          if (userConvos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const userId = userConvos[key];
            const result = await fetchUserData(userId);

            convoObj[key] = {
              userName: result.userName,
              userId: result.userId
            }
          }
        }

        commit('updateConvoObj', convoObj);
      }
    }
  });
```

then call your actions before using getter in your `sample.vue`:

```
await this.$store.dispatch('fetchAndUpdateConvoObj');
convoObj = this.$store.getters('getConvoObj');
```

wait for db and update store, then get its state.
doesnt make sense ?

### Use vuexfire to connect your store directly to Realtime Database

another approach is this.

use vuexfire, then the state of the store is always up-to-date to realtime database, so you can call getters without calling actions.
i got tired to refactor / write a code, so google some sample if you wanna use that plugin :)

i refactored the original code a lot, so there should be some typo or mistake.
plz revise is if you find one.

Comment: 1 vote  for `but you should not do like this, because getters are not meant to be asynchronous by design.`