# How to delay return in Vuex getters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am learning Vuex and I am trying to delay the value returned in a getter. Something like this, which does not work:

```
getters: {
    myGetter: state => {
        if(state.myProperty1 === 'value1'){
            setTimeout(() => {
                return 'resultA'                
            }, 1000);
        }
        else if(state.myProperty1 === 'value2'){
            setTimeout(() => {
                return 'resultB'                
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I am also learning actions and mutations but not sure if this practice is needed here (as I am not changing the state)?

I found similar posts but much more complex and have not been able to understand how to implement this yet.

Comment: Getters need to be sync. Similar to normal Vue `computed` properties. This is most likely XY problem. What is the point of that "delay" you want?

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220270/async-await-not-working-for-vuex-getter-but-works-for-log

Comment: @MichalLevý OK thanks, I didn't know it needed to be sync. Basically I am building a dashboard UI with many animated slide-in/out transitions based on what the user clicks on. The value returned by the getter here will trigger a v-if directive. It needs to be returned about 200ms after the user clicks for the slide-in effect to initiate first, in order to prevent a jerky entry in the dom. Maybe there is a better way to delay a v-if?

Comment: Watch the value of the getter within your component and set the delay there, as opposed to attempting to set it in the getter.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks, i'll definately try that!